# Android: How to programmatically enable "Use wireless networks" in My Location

Tags: android, location

I've been searching for it and till now i know that GPS can't be enable programmatically. but i didn't find nothing about enabling wireless networks in location & security settings. can it be set, or is it same like GPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options are not available via API except your app is running on rooted device. The workaround is to send user to preferences screen and ask him to enable these options.